# Are my "close" votes being neglected?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions

I have flagged many questions as "Duplicate" in [jquery-mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-mobile), but none of them is closed, my votes stand alone.

Some of them are recent (1 week) and others are old. I am afraid that they don't appear in "Close Votes" queue.

Below are some of them:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/q/22066359/1771795
2. [Check localstorage to decide which screen to load [jquery/javascript]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22064975/1771795)
3. https://stackoverflow.com/q/21930414/1771795
4. https://stackoverflow.com/q/22409066/1771795
5. [Add div attribute when resize window in jquerymobile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22143710/1771795)
6. [jqueryvalidation error appears in the textbox rather than label](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22461022/1771795)
7. [Can you display a search keyboard in a PhoneGap app on iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22570905/1771795)
8. [jQM navigating to page programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20859476/1771795) (Dec '13)
9. [jquery dialog not coming up on pageload](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20651652/1771795) (Dec '13)
10. And more...

Could someone check [jquery-mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery-mobile) "Close Votes" queue, please?

Edit: Thanks @George Stocker for your quick action.

Comment: The close vote queue is a little large at the moment. They have been doing a [little fudging of the numbers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223497/lets-burn-down-the-close-queue) so I can't tell you the exact size but it is **at least** 17,500 questions deep (maybe as much as 100,000). As such it may take a little while to get to these

Comment: @RichardTingle I'm aware of that, and before less than 2 months, the queue was wiped. What worries me is that, my votes are alone.

Comment: the phase 1 and phase 2 fuzzying stages were wiped out but not the whole queue. However, I believe in phase 3 fuzzying only questions with 2+ flags/votes are listed so you are right that your votes won't be in the queue *yet*

Comment: @Omar I dont think the queue was completely wiped. They were only limiting what was available in the queue to help get rid of all the questions that only needed 1-2 votes.

Comment: It seems to me that some of these questions were not seen by that many people. I don't know how well the number of views can act as an indicator for how likely a post is going to be acted on in review but I'd suspect that there's a correlation. I've noticed that some of my close votes in [tag:requirejs] (to mention just one tag I'm active in and which is not very popular) can linger for a long time.

Comment: @Louis true, this could be a reason. jQM isn't as popular as jQuery, however, 80% of jQM questions are tagged with jQuery.

Comment: @JoshMein as far as I remember, the queue reached less than 1k votes.

Comment: @Omar The jQuery tag probably helps visibility but the presence of a jQM tag might put off those who are otherwise fine with jQuery. That's the impression I get with RequireJS questions: they may get the JavaScript tag too but people see the RequireJS tag and decide to not look at them because they don't know RequireJS (and I don't blame them).

Comment: @Omar The queue reached less than 1k questions because they were limiting what was showing in it like I already said. Once they got rid of all the questions needing only 1 close vote, they increased the queue to questions needing 2 close vote. Rinse and Repeat.

Comment: @josh thanks, I didn't know that. I should visit Meta more often.

Comment: see: [Don't let flag-to-close flags linger for months in flag purgatory](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203670/dont-let-flag-to-close-flags-linger-for-months-in-flag-purgatory)